Cross Account RDS Backups: KMS Strategy
I am in the process of defining our KMS key strategy in our AWS multi-account environment, specifically for use with RDS Aurora and AWS Backup.
I need to make use of a Customer key for our RDS storage encryption to support cross account backups with AWS Backup. However, I am trying to decide on the correct approach for how cross-account keys are stored and accessed. I have come up with two potential options that are fairly similar, and am wondering which is considered the best approach...
Option 1: Store Key in Audit/Security account and modify policy to enable 'Environment' account usage for RDS encryption.
Option 2: Store key in the 'Environment' account and modify policy for use in the Audit/Security account.
Which option is considered the best practice, and more secure?

I would go for Option 2. That key belongs to that 'environment' account so it should be kept there. Then adjust the policy for any external account/service that needs access to it. And it seems Option 1 is not possible.
